# Is it possible to auto-indent only the current line on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-indent

On Atom (and many other editors), there is the auto-indent command which allows us to auto-indent the line the cursor is on. Is there an equivalent in Visual Studio Code ?

I know there is the formatter action on Visual Studio Code but from what i have seen, it can be used only to :

- format a selection (ctrl-K ctrl-F)
- format the hole document (ctrl + shift + I)

I would like to be able to format the line the cursor is on without reformating the whole document and without having to make a selection.

Basically, i would like to configure the [TAB] key so that when i press [TAB], it auto-indents only the line the cursor is on :

- if there is nothing written on the line, it just put the cursor at the right place so that when i start writting, the code is correctly indented.
- if there is already something written on the line, it audo-indents the line

Is it possible ?

Comment: I tried to see if I could create a macro to do select-line-format-selection-deselect-line, but it seems there aren't even workable macros _at all_.   A solution along those lines would be welcome.

Comment: @GreenAsJade, it works for me? https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gLMP.gif

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for taking a look.  If I put my cursor on your line 3 and hit "TAB", it incorrectly indents an extra 4 spaces (Indent-Line is called) instead of remaining correctly indented, which would be the behaviour of select-line-format-selection-deselect-line started from your line 3.   IE TAB should have the same behaviour wherever the cursor is: set the line to the correct indentation (this is what Atom, emacs and friends do).

Comment: @GreenAsJade I see the same behavior of Tab in Atom as well as VSCode. See this atom Gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D3Cx.gif

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, the behaviour is the same on unpopulated rows. The goal is to idtent populated rows correctly consistently with TAB.  
 This is Atom: https://imgur.com/a/yjp34

Comment: Got it now, I will check if something like this is there

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! Yep, would be great if we could find something for this

Comment: I guess if +150 doesn't get the answer within a couple of days, then it's just not possible eh?   It's a shame: VSC feels really nice, but not having macros is ... astounding.

Comment: You should file a feature request at their github repository. I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 4):

So I have skimmed through the source code and seems there is no setting currently available to make this happen. There is a lot of work happening in pipeline for indentation

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17868

VSCode use Monaco Editor under the hood

https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/612

The current python configs are located in

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/python

I tried, but understanding how all this integrates and works together just to fix one indent issue was just overwhelming. So I would just for the time being open a enhancement request with VScode and let the experts take a call and do the job

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to find a solution!

Comment: Hi @Tarun, i was wondering if you could share the link to the enhancement request you created (if you did) to see if there is new about this ? If not, i'll create a request when i get a moment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to humbly suggest that you are looking for the solution in the wrong place.

I would suggest the following setting:

```js
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
```

You have focused on "tab" doing the correct indentation. But with this setting you need not press the tab key at all. Just type the line with a normal return at the end. Visual Studio Code will then indent (and format) that line correctly.

Comment: But doing this adds another line after the one that you are trying to indent....   the TAB is to correctly indent a line without changing anything else.

Comment: You could format an existing line with keyboard shortcuts: Ctrl+I Ctrl+K Ctrl+F

Comment: If we are talking about JavaScript, I would recommend using Prettier and autosave. Then your file will be auto indented frequently without you doing anything at all.

Comment: Melbourn unfortunately, that formats the whole document, right?   There often (regrettably) are some sections of the document that should not be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the extension [emacs-tab](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emacs-tab.emacs-tab), you can do this:

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "emacs-tab.reindentCurrentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Which, as far as I understand you, does exactly what you want (and doesn't format the line in other ways, such as breaking it if it is too long, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=avasilev.tab-anywhere) extension worked for me, and allows typing Tab with the cursor mid-line to get proper indentation similar to what I was used to on Emacs.

Note that it basically does the same as the extension recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427820/10682164) answer but at the time of this writing that extension appears to be unmaintained and has some open issues.

Comment: Thanks for mentionning this. I didn't tested it yet but looks promising thanks